# fadeOut not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I am new to web design. I am making my resume now. I have navigation div like this:

```
<div id="nav" class="grid_12">
    <div id="Home" class="grid_3">
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Life" class="grid_3">
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#">Life</a>
        </div>
        <img src="img/someimg.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="Portfolio" class="grid_3">
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Contact" class="grid_3">
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I have a script for the navigation:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    $("#nav img").hide();
    $(".button").focus(function() {
        $(this).next("img").fadeIn("slow");
    }).blur(function() {
    $(this).next("img").fadeOut("slow");
    }); 
</script>
```

I want it so when someone holds the mouse over the button the image will appear under it. It is properly hiding the image, but fadeIn not working. I have no idea why it is not working.

Comment: You probably want to use `.mouseenter` or `.on('mouseenter', ` instead of `.focus`

Comment: What @ExplosionPills said + use the dom ready event.

Answer (score 0):

`.focus` is bound to the ["focus"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_%28computing%29) event (I linked to a description of what it is rather than the event standard).  This is most common when you tab to or click on text inputs, but it can apply to other elements as well.

The `mouseenter` (also `mouseover`, but the former is not triggered repeatedly when child elements are also hovered) event occurs when a mouse enters an element.  The opposite is `mouseleave` (`mouseout`).  http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Answer (score 0):

try putting your script inside a `ready` event of the document :

```
<script type="text/javascript>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#nav img").hide();
            $(".button").focus(function() {
                $(this).next("img").fadeIn("slow");
            }).blur(function() {
                $(this).next("img").fadeOut("slow");
            }); 
         });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using the 960gs, and one thing I have noticed is this: your four grid_3 divs are nested within your grid_12. The 960gs includes two classes called `.alpha` and `.omega` to fix the nested margins when a grid is inside a parent grid. You need to put the `.alpha` class on the first child div - which in this case is your `<div id="#home">` and the `.omega` class on the last child div which is your `<div id="Contact">`. This will fix the margins you will have on the internal nested four grid_3's.